# Which is better and which should we prefer to use, tilde(~) or caret (^) in package.JSON?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, package.json, webdriver-io, semantic-versioning

I am working on Automation testing project
Unable to figure out what should be prefer to use between tilde(~) and caret(^) in dependencies and devDependencies

Framework we are using - Chai-mocha(webderiverio)

I am aware of the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^), but unable to figure out which is better and which should be used in our package.json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)